# alternative of URL scheme for launching application in ios from another application?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, url-scheme

Target Application is not having any URL scheme, and i want invoke it with my application.
I also want to redirect to Apple store if the user doesn't have that application installed.
Please tell me if there is any other way to open an application from Cordova plugin or JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. But unless you have a jailbroken device, there's no way to open another app other than via URL scheme, i.e. (Swift): `UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:)`
This is so by intention since Apple wants the apps sandboxed and therefore strictly limits the ways apps can interact. Launching via URL is the only way they permit app launching.

Comment: Will apple restrict my app while publishing if i use URL scheme ? do they have any policy regarding interaction between Application in IOS ?

Comment: Notice that Apple recommends using Universal Links as the method for deep linking into an app. you can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

You can still use URI schemes, but their usage is not recommended and may result some errors e.g. in Safari when the app is not installed.